# Cycle2 slider with multiple divs - can only get it to work on JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My aim is to make a slider that has two divs. One with text and one with an image alongside each other. However, I have been unable to do this by trying my own code at home or even the cycle2 support pages. I did manage to find a JSFiddle where someone had been having a similar issue. I updated the JSFiddle which is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pmffy/13/) and that seems to work and shows what I want to achieve. The bizarre thing is if I try the same code on my computer or if I set up my own JSFiddle with the same code and external resources I cannot make this slider work.

The Html:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" 
            data-cycle-fx="carousel"
            data-cycle-timeout="3600"
            data-cycle-slides="> div.home-block"
           data-cycle-carousel-visible="1" 
           >

<div class="home-block">
<div class="brief">
</div><div class="examples">
</div>
</div>

<div class="home-block">
<div class="brief">
</div><div class="examples">
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

and the CSS

```
div.home-block
{
    height : 500px
}

div.home-block div.brief
{
    width : 25% ;
    height : 301px ;
    background-color : black ;
    color : white ;
    font-family : Arial ;
    display : inline-block ;
    vertical-align : top
}

div.home-block div.examples
{
    width : 70% ;
    height : 400px ;
    background-image : url("http://www.luxurylifestylemag.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/porsche911solo.jpg") ;
    background-size : 100% ;
    background-repeat : no-repeat ;
    background-position : top ;
    display : inline-block ;
    vertical-align : top
}
```

I have tried a lot of things, including putting the divs inside list items, anchor tags, span classes. However, none of it works for me. I am using the correct script tags to reference cycle2. If I just do a simple slideshow with images inside a div it will work. However, divs inside divs will not work - the exception is the JSFiddle I posted above.

I have put the exact same code and external Rescources in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84camohz/), but it doesn't work. Why is it not working?

Comment: your jquery carousel min js file is not found https://jsfiddle.net/84camohz/jquery.cycle2.carousel.min.js
Try to add it again. Also the one you have added might be http link which the fiddle stores as a https link

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what I was doing wrong on JSFiddle. When I tried at home I was making a simple error, but thought the problem was more complicated. Another few hours to learn a simple lesson.